# Failed to programmatically uninstall a font in Windows CE

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, windows-ce

I would like to programmatically uninstall and delete 'simsun.ttc' font collection from '\Hard Disk\Fonts' on WinCE 5. I try to use RemoveFontResource() function but it fails and the last error is (0x2) (The system cannot find the file specified). I definitely know that the file is present.

```
...
BOOL res = RemoveFontResource(L"\\Hard Disk\\Fonts\\simsun.ttc");
DWORD err = GetLastError(); // 0x2

...
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the font, or did it come in the OS?  If it came in the OS (which is likely) then you probably can't delete it.  Why would you want to?  Are you trying to save space?  If so, get a new OS image without the font in it.